# Htaccess some directory, subdirectory usage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want rewriting "cat/" => x.php
"cat/sample-title" => y.php?t=$1 with htaccess.

I writed rewrite rules;

```
RewriteRule ^cat/ x.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)$ y.php?s=$1   [L]
```

but always cat/ rewriting to y.php?s=$1

Comment: Looks like you only need a `$` anchor  `RewriteRule ^cat/?$ x.php [L]` (also added `?` for optional `/`)

Comment: Thanks, but different forwarding page, first rule forwarding x.php, second rule forwarding y.php

Comment: Hold on, I'll put a complete answer below.

Comment: Thanks, i waiting your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing two issues. The first is that both the first and second rules' patterns are matched by `^cat/`, so the second one supplants the first after it is rewritten. You will need to anchor it with `$`, and also may want to permit an optional trailing `/` with `/?`.

Then, to differentiate it from the first, the second one must match *one or more* characters following the `cat/`, so instead of `(.*)`, you should use `(.+)`.

I would also change their order (though it is not strictly necessary in this case)

```
# Ensure one or more characters with .+
RewriteRule ^cat/(.+)$ y.php?s=$1 [L]
# Anchored with optional trailing /
RewriteRule ^cat/?$ x.php [L]
```